# Group duration errors by ranges in JMeter HTML report

Tags: jmeter

Currently JMeter produces HTML report as shown below, making every single duration error a separate entry. How do I group them in ranges? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Are you using ANT or APDEX?

Comment: It's using APDEX

Comment: In the Type of Error has variance in the milliseconds, you cannot group. Because the error 1 has 3 errors for 3396 ms which are already grouped.